# Sticky headers print halfway down page if table is scrolled before hitting print button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been using javascript to make my table headers sticky on my page.  I'm using multiple tables per page and the sticky headers are working well.  I am now trying to add in the ability to print off the tables and have successfully managed to implement a print button for each table.

I am however having an issue with printing the table after it has been scrolled down.  The table header is printing off halfway down the table.  I'm looking for a way to reset the header position to the top of the table when the print button is hit.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've attached my current JavaScript below which has the issue.

```
document.getElementById("wrap").addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
    this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});

document.getElementById("wrap2").addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
    this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});

document.getElementById("wrap3").addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
    this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});


function printDiv1() {
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("printableTable").innerHTML;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}

function printDiv2() {
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("printableTable2").innerHTML;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}

function printDiv3() {
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("printableTable3").innerHTML;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}
```

My best idea for fixing this was to use the following code, however, this stopped the print function working entirely.

```
function printDiv1() {
    var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
    this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("printableTable2").innerHTML;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}
```

If anyone knows of a solution that will allow me to reset the header position to the top of the table when the print button is hit please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using JavaScript to scroll to the top of the table before printing.  This forces the headers back to the top of the table.

This is my working function:

```
function printDiv1() {
    document.getElementById("wrap").scrollTop = 0;

    setTimeout(
        function(){
            window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = 
            document.getElementById("printableTable").innerHTML;
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
            window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
        }
    , 500);

}
```

Comment: If this is the solution you went with you should accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media print in a stylesheet and then override your styles that are giving it a fixed position.

```
@media print {
   // These styles are only applied when printing
}
```

So for example, something like this...

```
@media print {
    thead {
        position: static !important;
    }
}
```

There are also other ways to setup styles for printing, for example creating a separate stylesheet and calling it like this...notice **media="print"**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Here is a [good article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) on print styles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I tried out this method but couldn't get it to work.  I think I must've been using the 'translate:transform()' incorrectly.  I've since worked out a way to solve this by using JavaScript to scroll back to the top of the table before printing.